# unable to use hp deskjet 1010 drivers

Tags: printing

I'm trying to install HP Deskjet 1010 printer, I can't use the CD that come with the printer, I don't now how I can run it. I can't download driver directly from HP page, and the ubuntu system don't find the drivers. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install HPLIP from [HP Linux Imaging and Printing](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet/deskjet_1010_series.html) site. Hit the link. It will take you to the DeskJet 1010 page. From there just download HPLIP and follow the instruction.

Note: You need to run it with root privileges.